# Laravel 4 ajax with partial views

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

im new with laravel 4 started a few days ago. My problem is simple, i have a combobox which the client or the user changes and renders a "partial" view.

[image]

this is my first view. OnChange:

[image]

will render that simple message through javascript

my problem is if i place the value "by hand" it will only show the partial view:

[image]

this is my function in the controller

```
    public function getTeste1() {
    $id = Input::get('value');
    if($id=="")
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('home.user');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('home.user2')->with('ides',$id);
    }
}
```

this my javascript function:

```
function showCustomer(str)
{
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp==null)
{
alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
return;
}
var url="";
url="?value="+str;
//url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
// alert(url);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(true);
}
```

this is my view:

```
<h1>Home</h1>

<p>Welcome to your Home. You rock!</p>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showCustomer(this.value)">
<option value="0">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

this is my partial view:

```
@if($ides!=0)
<div id="txtHint"> <b>Person info will be listed here -> {{ $ides }} </b></div>
@endif
```

I know why i have this problem, i don't know how to avoid it if you guys know it will be very helpful, or other away to do it.

Thank you,

Gonçalo Moura

EDITED:
if i use your solution it will show like this:
[image]

StateChanged function:

```
function stateChanged()
{
   if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
   {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;

      // alert(document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML);

   }
}
```

jquery function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#users").change(function() {
  $.get('http://localhost/LoginProject/public/home/teste1?value=' + $(this).val(),         function(data) {
    $("#txtHint").html(data);
  });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show `stateChanged` function?

Answer (score 3):

i will give you a simpler approach for overall design.

you don't need to touch anything in controller.

return the same view for both with or without ajax request.

just make a little change in the layout.

```
@if(!Request::ajax())
<html>
....
.... //the whole layout
</html>
@else
{{$content}}
@endif
```

simple logic.

if the request is not ajax, return the view with the whole template.

if the request is ajax, return only the view.

Comment: i have done some research but im a bit lost with this aproach. i already have a layout which i uptade that view. the {{ $content }} its my view i simple add the partialview. i am very new at this, and i have been struggling with this for quite a while. What i want to do is throught a combobox value i can search in my database and update a table with that data without refreshing the page. There are several tutorials about laravel ajax but what i found was not useful or maybe i didnt understand. can you help me a bit more for this specific example. Thank you very much for your anwser.

Comment: in which part you are facing the problem. tell me exactly that portion so that my example can be more useful.

Comment: i just want to update a div onchange of that dropdow with data from my database. But i wanna use ajax i don't want to refresh the page. My point it works the way i do it, but if the user change the url and add the "url"+"?value=2" for example it will only show my partialview and will not show the dropdow because of my controller. I have been searching for angularjs and some tutorials they have nice examples what i want to do. Its hard to understand tho. I thought maybe is there a simple way to do it

Comment: i mostly do server work, on client side, i use jquery for convenience (i don't know javascript much):D. is jquery an option for you?

Comment: i had a jquery function which worked but still i have the same problem with the controller which i had with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Because you tell it to display only partial view if `value` is found in URL.
This is causing problem for you

```
if($id=="")
{
    $this->layout->content = View::make('home.user');
}
else
{
    $this->layout->content = View::make('home.user2')->with('ides',$id);
}
```

Change your controller method to this.

```
public function getTeste1()
{
    $id = Input::get('value', null);

    $this->layout->content = View::make('home.user')->with('id', $id);
}
```

And view to this

```
<h1>Home</h1>

<p>Welcome to your Home. You rock!</p>

<form>
    <select name="users" onchange="showCustomer(this.value)">
        <option value="0">Select a person:</option>
        <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
        <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
        <option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
        <option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="txtHint">
    @if ($id)
        show detail without AJAX call. Since ID is in URL, you can get the info directly
    @else
        show info that this container will hold some data after AJAX call
    @endif
</div>
```

And intend your code, for your own good :)

Comment: i know that, the problem is that i don't know how to avoid it

Comment: check the answer. It is good to do some logic in views as well.

Comment: thank you for your answer maybe im not understanding :\ but i edited using your code.